# Execute PHP command inside of preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

Is it possible to execute a php command e.g. `strtolower()` through `preg_replace()`?

I would like to make just a party of a array in lower case letters and the other part into uppercase. The problem is that the letters are dynamically changing and are not fixed, just one word stays the same but the rest not.

e.g.
arraypart1 (should stay uppercase) (constantword)+arraypart2 (both should change to lower case letters)

arraypart2 is also changing in size of character numbers.

Comment: Use [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you want to do, but I think it's the following: extract words from a string and lowercase/uppercase some of them according to their presence in one of arrays. `preg_replace_callback` will help you.

PHP 5.3 and higher:

```
$initial = "Mary had a little lamb";
$toupper = array("Mary", "lamb");
$tolower = array("had", "any");
$out = preg_replace_callback(
   "/\b(?P<word>\w+)\b/", // for every found word 
   function($matches) use ($toupper, $tolower) { // call this function 
      if (in_array($toupper, $matches['word'])) // is this word in toupper array?
          return strtoupper($matches['word']);

      if (in_array($tolower, $matches['word'])) // is this word in tolower array?
          return strtolower($matches['word']);

      // ... any other logic
      return $matches['word']; // if nothing was returned before, return original word
   },
   $initial);
print $out; // "MARY had a little LAMB"
```

If you have other arrays that need to be taken in account, put them in `use` statement so that they are available inside anonymous function.

PHP >= 4.0.5:

```
$initial = "Mary had a little lamb";
$toupper = array("Mary", "lamb");
$tolower = array("had", "any");

function replace_callback($matches) {  
   global $tolower, $toupper;
      if (in_array($toupper, $matches['word'])) // is this word in toupper array?
          return strtoupper($matches['word']);

      if (in_array($tolower, $matches['word'])) // is this word in tolower array?
          return strtolower($matches['word']);

      // ... any other logic
      return $matches['word']; // if nothing was returned before, return original word
   }

$out = preg_replace_callback(
   "/\b(?P<word>\w+)\b/", // for every found word 
   'replace_callback', // call this function
   $initial);
print $out; // "MARY had a little LAMB"
```

As you see, nothing changed significantly, I just replaced anonymous function with a named one. To provide it with other arrays of strings, refer to them with `global` keyword.

Answer (score -1):

I hope I understand you correctly ,`preg_replace` is a function and like all other functions you can do:

```
preg_replace(strtolower($val),$pattern,$someString);
```

`preg_replace` would be called with the lowercase version of `$val`

Comment: No. This seems wrong. It's very likely that the point of question is to distinguish some input values (`$someString`)

Comment: So what? i answered the question, he can call strtolower on whatever he wants, i just gave an example ,why did you downvote?

Comment: `preg_replace` won't do the trick here. `preg_replace_callback` would.